# image validation using image header in codeigniter to prevent hacking

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I want a method for validating image files.

I have tried validating using image type and its formats and size. I need another validation with high accuracy.

I am asking because my site has hacked by an uploaded image file containing code. The hacker has written code in .png format and uploaded it as an image in my site. From that moment he started hacking my site.

Kindly help me to get a high validation for an image file using its header.

I have validation like below:

```
 function upload()
    {
        //set preferences
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt|pdf';
        $config['max_size']    = '100';

        //load upload class library
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
        {
            // case - failure
            $upload_error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_file_view', $upload_error);
        }
        else
        {
            // case - success
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $data['success_msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your file <strong>' . $upload_data['file_name'] . '</strong> was successfully uploaded!</div>';
            $this->load->view('upload_file_view', $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: rename it before store it in DB.

Comment: use php mime content type to check the file:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have allowed filetypes of txt and pdf. You should use

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
```

If it is images you are uploading.

Comment: it will validate only the type of the image I need to validate the content of the image..It is possible to write code in .png file..In my case i have seen a file which is in .png format and the file can't be opened as image.I used note pad to view it there is some set of codes in .png format..So better provide validation regarding the image headrs

Comment: Once uploaded the file upload data array has the field is_image, is this not the field you need to check in that case. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data